# Accessing Google analytics api using api key

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I'm trying to implement Google analytics API using API key to make it available without authorization. But i can get examples using CLIENT ID in google developer console itself. Can anyone help me with an example using api key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google Analytics' EmbedAPI](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/) will allow you to display your Google Analytics via javascript, and users will be able to log in on page.

You will still need to get your clientAPI, but then users will be able to login independently.

The [javascript code is described in the dev guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/devguide) and a sample is below:

```
<script>
    gapi.analytics.ready(function() {

    // Step 3: Authorize the user.

    var CLIENT_ID = 'Insert your client ID here';

    gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
                container: 'auth-button',
                clientid: CLIENT_ID,
    });
</script>
```

The API limit should be no problem, its 50,000 calls per day.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to access Google Analytics API with the API key.   You must use Open Authentication.

If you are trying to access your own data you can use  a [service account](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount).  Create new credentials choose Service Account.

You can then take the service account email address:

> 1046123799103-nk421gjc2v8mlr2qnmmqaak04ntb1dbp@developer.gserviceaccount.com

Add it as a user at the **ACCOUNT** level it is very important that it be at the ACCOUNT level it wont work other wise.   Your application with then be able to access your Google Analytics data with out a log in.

Without knowing what language you are working with I cant give you any examples.

**Update:**

If as you say you are planning on doing this with JavaScript then you will have to go with Oauth2 and request access.  There is no way to use a Service account with JavaScript.

There for I strongly recommend that you find a server sided programing language to do this in.  Even if it did work with JavaScript you would end up running out of quota on the API before to long.

Comment: I'm trying to implement using javascript!!

Comment: You cant use a service account with JavaScript,  you will have to use a server sided programing language.

Comment: @DalmTo it's still valid also for API V4? I'm trying to access server to server, using the api key and service account, but no way to get authentication. (Where do you get the service account email??) Here is the code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43685261/analytics-reporting-v4-with-api-key

Comment: API key only works with public APIs.  Service account email is found in google developer console it ends with @developer.gserviceaccount.com